# How do I disconnect and reconnect this?

Tags: electrical, uk, connectors

How do I safely undo and re-attach this connector? it connects an armoured cable to the power outlet in the shed. I'll turn off the mains obviously. And then do I just undo it with a spanner and pull it out?

I need to re-route the cable and need to disconnect it to do that.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the inside of the box?

Comment: Looks like a cable grip fitting that rotating the lower part with a spanner just squeezes the cable that feds through it. You would probably have to open the cabinet, disconnect individual wires, and slide the cable through the connector.

Comment: that is not an electrical connector

Answer (score 3):

That is a gland connector which seals the outer cover of the cable and grips the protective outer wires then the conductors continue into the box / device to the connections.

So you have to undo the internal conductors and then release that cinnector.

Make sure the supply is **off**.

We always used to undo the internal fixing nut and the connecting wires and leave the gland assembled to the cable - much easier.